# Installed Web Inspector but can't invoke it.

Tags: windows, google-chrome, sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin

First I tried to install using Package Control Install but wasn't listed among the available packages. I then cloned Web Inspector from github and copied the folder into `C:\Documents and Settings\Dad\Application Data\Sublime Text 3\Packages`.

Now in the Preferences menu under Package Settings there's a entry for Web Inspector, under that the key bindings default file and the settings default files are both populated so it seems it may be properly installed but when I try to invoke it using `ctl+shift+r` nothing happens.

I noticed the `swi.sublime-settings` file listed the path to Chrome as `C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\chrome.exe` I changed to the real path `C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe` but that didn't help.

My OS is windows xp, the version of Web Inspector is 1.4

Comment: I just tried f12 but it just brought up chrome.